# How to use nested select

Tags: mysql

i have the following table structure
table "location" has
    - id
    - parentLocation_id (relation to itself)
    - name

let assume we have the following data:

```
id  parentLocation_id  name

1         null           Egypt
2          1             Cairo
3          2             Zamalek
```

here we have three levels of locations , i want to get all levels (locations) that have id =1 or child of location_id.

The result must have all the three locations if i selected Egypt location (get all inheritance level).

i tried the following

```
select l.id from Location as l where l.id = 1 or l.id in (select id from Location where parentLocation_id= l.id);
```

here the result is not correct , and here i reached to the second level only.

How can i do this??

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Can you only have 3 levels, or is there the slightest chance you could have 4 or more? Like continent (Africa)? or suberb (downtown)?

Comment: I have only three levels i dont need more than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another answer that may fit your desired results better. Note that there are three (3) places that you need to put the desired id

```
SELECT l1.id AS select_id
FROM location l1
WHERE l1.id IN (
    SELECT l2.id 
    FROM location l2, location l3 
    WHERE l2.id = 1 OR l2.parentLocation_id = 1 OR (l2.parentLocation_id = l3.id AND l3.parentLocation_id = 1)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This query works if you always have three levels.

```
SELECT * 
FROM location l1, location l2, location l3 
WHERE l1.id = 1 
  AND l1.id = l2.parentLocation_id  
  AND l2.id = l3.parentLocation_id
```

Do you need it to pull out only 2 levels? For example,
    Egypt, Cairo if it didn't have a 3rd level (Zamalek)?

Comment: But I need this select to be a sub select so i cant select * i want to select id as

select id from Location where id in (SELECT * 
FROM location l1, location l2, location l3 
WHERE l1.id = 1 
  AND l1.id = l2.parentLocation_id  
  AND l2.id = l3.parentLocation_id)


How can i do this ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What you want to store is a heirarchy, and is quite tricky to implement properly in a database.

Have a look at this for more info: [Trees and Hierarchies in SQL](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/more-trees-hierarchies-in-sql)